# sql/presto: how to find records that exist before but not current day for each day

Tags: mysql, sql, data-manipulation, presto

I have a data like the following:

```
 item day
  a   1
  b   1 
  c   1
  a   2
  c   2
  d   2
  a   3 
  d   3
```

and the desired result is to find the for each day, what records disappeared before this day. Desired results:

```
disappeared_item   day_of_interest
        b           2   (as of the second day, only b disappeared)
       b,c          3   (as of the fourth day, b and c disappeared)
```

i thought of finding out the max(day) of each item but got stack in terms of how to get the accumulated items for each day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
items AS ( SELECT DISTINCT item
           FROM test ),
days AS ( SELECT DISTINCT day
           FROM test )
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(items.item) disappeared_item,
       days.day day_of_interest
FROM items
CROSS JOIN days
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
               FROM test
               WHERE test.item = items.item
                 AND test.day < days.day )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                   FROM test
                   WHERE test.item = items.item
                     AND test.day = days.day )
GROUP BY days.day;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c35dbe8b9b0a0e00f69c542a70be4bfc